# How do I delete the last empty page in an OpenOffice Writer .odt document

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I have an `.odt` document (originally a one-page resume imported from a `.docx` Word document) and it now has an extra empty second page. The document text is all placed in a 2-column table and the table runs over to the next page, even though there is no content in the next page. I tried to use the `Delete` key to no avail. How could I get rid of the last empty page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to delete that last empty page.

Go to the last empty page and right-click inside the table. From the context menu select `Row > Delete`.

That deleted the empty page. That table row, even though empty, was taking space into the next page.